# How to get specific array element php

Tags: php, arrays, post

Everybody, I'm have an `$_POST['input']` request with this:

```
Array
(
    ['Имя'] => 
    ['Город'] => 
    ['Контактный телефон'] => sdfsdf
    ['email'] => sdfsdf
    ['Площадь(м2)'] => 
    ['Материал'] => 
    ['Толщина стен(мм)'] => 
    ['Высота потолков(мм)'] => 
    ['Кол-во окон'] => 
    ['Топливо'] => 
    ['Пожелания'] => asdasd
)
```

How to get value of the element of this array, something like `$_POST['input']['email']` for example (this does not work)?

Comment: how does your form looks like ?

Comment: How do you access your post array is based on your form and input elements.

Comment: Elements in form looks like this: <input style="width: 300px;" name="input['email']" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you have single quotes around the word `'email'` inside the array key:

Notice the difference:

```
<?php

 $_POST['input'] = array ('...' => '...',
                          'email' => 'xyzabc',
                          "'email'" => 'sdfsdf');

Array
(
    [input] => Array
        (
            [...] => ...
            [email] => xyzabc
            ['email'] => sdfsdf
        )

)
```

So in order to correctly get the key you need to check it as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['input']["'email'"])) {
     echo $_POST['input']["'email'"];
}
```

**Result**:

```
sdfsdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not write

`$_POST['input']['email']`

Write

`echo $_POST['email']`

And it will output `sdfsdf`

Answer (score 0):

if this has been submitted though post request just look for `$_post['email'].`

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['input']['email']` is the correct place  to look.

Check if your the names are exact "email" (may be cirilic E in one of the places ?)

Try some of the others:

`echo $_POST['input']['Имя']`

You may need to check if the request is empty:

```
$email = isset($_POST['input']['email'])? $_POST['input']['email'] : 'no email';
```

Comment: Request is ok, think, something wrong with syntax, and braces, with you code:Array
(
    ['Имя'] => 
    ['Город'] => 
    ['Контактный телефон'] => sdfsdf
    ['email'] => sdfsdf
    ['Площадь(м2)'] => 
    ['Материал'] => 
    ['Толщина стен(мм)'] => 
    ['Высота потолков(мм)'] => 
    ['Кол-во окон'] => 
    ['Топливо'] => 
    ['Пожелания'] => asdasd
)

no email